# How to not make text not "jumpy" when fading in word by word?

Tags: jquery, css

I am having issues fading in word by word without making the first word jump abruptly to the left when the second word appears.

I've included the jfiddle to show what I mean. http://jsfiddle.net/6czap/504/

I would appreciate if someone can tell me how I can fix it. Thanks.

```
<div class="headline">
Digital Journalist
</div>


var $title = $(".headline:first"), text = $.trim($title.text()),
words = text.split(" "), html = "";

for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
html += "<span>" + words[i] + ((i+1) === words.length ? "" : " ") + "       </span>";
};
$title.html(html).children().hide().each(function(i){
  $(this).delay(i*900).fadeIn(700);
});
$title.find("span").promise().done(function(){
    $el.text(function(i, text){
       return $.trim(text);
    });            
});
```

Comment: Not seeing any "jump" in your fiddle.

Comment: well.. uhm.... `body{ text-align: center;}` the center position of 1 word is *always* going to be different than the center position of 2 or more words.

Comment: Then how can I center the text so the transition would look smooth?

Answer (score 0):

It's because of

```
body {
    text-align: centre;
}
```

When a new word is added, the 'centre' is recalculated.

Also note that you assigned a class to the `<a>` but didn't use it.

Try using a margin instead of text-align:

```
.subtitle {
    margin-left: 40%;
}
```

Test it at http://jsfiddle.net/kdgm6rcm/1/

Comment: But then it shifts other text over as well. How can I prevent that? Thanks

Comment: Check out my updated fiddle. The icons below the "Digital Journalist" shifts to the right after applying the margin left css

Comment: Ah, that is because of `body { margin-left: 40% }` which entails everything in the body being moved 40% from the left. See my edit how instead of applying the change to `body` we explicitly changed `.subtitle`.

Comment: Close enough. I just need to play around with the margin.

Comment: Encapsulating the whole `.subtitle` area into a `div`, giving a fixed width, and fitting the `div` into the centre is also viable... http://jsfiddle.net/quxdkmng/2/

Comment: Please close this question if you are satisfied with the answer :)